# Separable morphism and smooth fibers

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a separable, dominant morphism of finite type between noetherian $k$-schemes for $k$ algebraically closed. Does it mean that

1. For a closed point $x \in X$, $f^{-1}(f(x))$ is smooth at $x$?
2. For a general $x \in X$ closed point, $f^{-1}(f(x))$ is smooth at $x$?

Comment: 1. No, certainly not. That would mean every fibre is smooth at every closed point. 2. Yes. It is even true that for a general $y \in Y$, $f^{-1}(y)$ is nonsingular. That is called "generic smoothness".

Comment: @PoohBear Could you suggest a reference for $(2)$? Note that $k$ could be of positive characteristic.

Comment: Take $Y=\mathrm{Spec}\, k$ and $X=\mathrm{Spec}\, k[x]/(x^2)$. Then 2 fails too. Need some hypothesis, more than just a Noetherian $k$-scheme.

Comment: @Mohan Thank you for the answer. I think I understand. I am a little bit confused with the definition in SGA-I-chapter X, definition $1.1$. This seems to rule out this example. Although the definition in Hartshorne does not. I will be very grateful if you could please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, I typed faster than my brain works --- I meant that my stronger statement for 2) holds if $X$ is nonsingular. (Your version should work if $X$ is generically reduced.) Anyway, I'll try to look up a reference.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to clarify in my example. If $k$ is of positive characteristic $p$, then you could also take, say $F:\mathbb{P}^1\to\mathbb{P}^1$, the Frobenius, to get counterexamples.